# Ruby Sinatra textarea displays variable string instead of variable value

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to set up a webapp using Sinatra, and I've got it working currently where the user can enter a list of URLs into a textarea, click submit, and then some code is ran on the URLs and the user is redirected to a second page to view the result. I'd like to remove the redirection and display the results in another textarea on the same page(or even re-use the same text area) but I've so far been unsuccessful in this venture. Instead of displaying the result, the second textarea just displays the <%=res%> and the submitted URLs disappear.

ERB page

```
<h1>Put URLs Here</h1>
<form method="POST" action="">
<p><textarea id="urls" name="urls" rows="20" cols="60">
</textarea></p>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<br />
<br />
<h1>Results</h1>
<p><textarea id="results" name="results" rows="20" cols="60">
  <%=res%>
</textarea></p>
```

app.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/ip' do
  erb :ip
end

post '/ip' do
  res = Hash.new("")
  u = params[:urls].lines("\n")
  list = Ipcheck.new()
  res = list.check(u)
  erb :ip, :locals => {'res' => res}
end
```

What am I doing wrong? I've searched and have not been able to find a solution to this specific problem.

Comment: are you familiar with AJAX? Seems to be what you're looking for, since you want to communicate with the server without refreshing the page. It's probably good to go through a tutorial on that.

Answer (score 0):

Use global variable instead of local.

```
<%= @res %>
```

and

```
@res = Hash.new("")
 u = params[:urls].lines("\n")
 list = Ipcheck.new()
 @res = list.check(u)
 erb :ip
```